# c++ set ordered iterating - Are results of iterating over set, ordered by standard?

Tags: c++, stl

Can I rely on the assumption (in other words: Is it guaranteed by standard?) that :

- `set<T>::begin()` will point to the smallest element in set?
- iterating over set, (from `set<T>::begin()` till `set<T>::end()`) will give elements in increasing order?
- and just to be sure: Do these properties hold for keys in `map`?

I mean `set` and `map` from `STL`.

P.S. I know abut `operator<()` and defining own comparators. Please ensure me about what standard says about this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on that by definition, depending on the element's (keys) `bool operator<` or the comparison functor passed as template parameter to the set (map). So the ordering will be from smallest to largest according to the comparator used.

In the C++11 standard, §23.2.4, dealing with requirements of Associative Containers:

> Each associative container is parameterized on Key and an ordering relation Compare that induces a strict weak ordering (25.4) on elements of Key. In addition, map and multimap associate an arbitrary type T with the Key. The object of type Compare is called the comparison object of a container.

Then, in the same section:

> The fundamental property of iterators of associative containers is that they iterate through the containers
>   in the non-descending order of keys where non-descending is defined by the comparison that was used to
>    construct them. For any two dereferenceable iterators i and j such that distance from i to j is positive,
>   value_comp(*j, *i) == false

where `value_comp` is the comparison function.

Comment: Could you refer to standard ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki I just added some quotes from the C++11 standard.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was curious about. Btw. Do you know if it applies to older C++ standards ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki absolutely, it has been there since C++ was standardised. In the C+103 standard (a revision on C++98) the relevant section is §23.1.2.

Answer (score 6):

The order depends on comparing functor used (third template argument on map, second on set). The default is `std::less<T>`, which gives sets/maps an ascending order, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  Yes.

Longer answer: both std::set and std::map take a second templated argument - a binary predicate to compare elements.  By default, this is std::less - a class implementing a single boolean function - which is, itself, defined in terms of operator <.

Unless you specify otherwise when instantiating the stl template, operator < will define the order of keys.  N.B. Weird things may happen if you use a boolean predicate that does not define a (partial) order. :)

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Longer answer should be "yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees".